# Format double type

Tags: .net

I need to format double type so that it has at least two digits after delimiter:

5     -> "5.00"

5.5   -> "5.50"

5.55  -> "5.55"

5.555 -> "5.555"

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Which language? You should put a tag with the language name. [tag:.net] is a framework, not a language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433539/format-double-type-with-minimum-number-of-decimal-digits/7433735#7433735) in another SO thread.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(FormatDecimal(1.678M));
    Console.WriteLine(FormatDecimal(1.6M));
    Console.ReadLine();

}

private static string FormatDecimal(decimal input)
{
    return Math.Abs(input - decimal.Parse(string.Format("{0:0.00}", input))) > 0 ?
        input.ToString() :
        string.Format("{0:0.00}", input);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try:

```
5.ToString("N2");
```

See [standard numeric format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

Comment: It won't work for the last case as there are three decimal places

Answer (score 1):

Try `String.Format("{0:0.00######}",value);` This will give you at least 2 decimal digits and a maximum of 8 digits.

Comment: Is there any way to make it without maximum decimal digits limitation?

Comment: No, I don't know about it. If you need more decimal digits, extend your format string with "#" signs.