# Format double type with minimum number of decimal digits

Tags: c#, .net

I need to format double type so that it has minimum two decimal digits but without limitation for maximum number of decimal digits:

```
5     -> "5.00"
5.5   -> "5.50"
5.55  -> "5.55"
5.555 -> "5.555"
5.5555 -> "5.5555"
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: So you want double convert to string and make sure it has minimum 2 decimal digits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(FormatDecimal(1.678M));
        Console.WriteLine(FormatDecimal(1.6M));
        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    private static string FormatDecimal(decimal input)
    {
        return Math.Abs(input - decimal.Parse(string.Format("{0:0.00}", input))) > 0 ?
            input.ToString() :
            string.Format("{0:0.00}", input);
    }
```

Answer (score 47):

You can use the `0` format specificer for non-optional digits, and `#` for optional digits:

```
n.ToString("0.00###")
```

This example gives you up to five decimal digits, you can add more `#` positions as needed.

Comment: Beware that the output will be culture specific. In some countries for example the decimal separator will be a ',' instead of a '.'. If you insist on a '.' use: `n.ToString("0.00###", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Answer (score 3):

Something like `ToString("0.00#")` should work

In this case it would be max to 3 decimal places, so add hash as required.