# Qt C++ equivalent to C# toString with custom format

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to find a Qt/C++ equivalent of C# `toString("00.00##")` (or different) custom formats.
Just some links to explain what do I want to achieve, in case if it's not clear enough:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings

[Format double type with minimum number of decimal digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433539/format-double-type-with-minimum-number-of-decimal-digits)

For a format: 00.00##:

```
1.23 -> 01.23
10 -> 10.00
0.535353 -> 00.5353
831.5 -> 831.50
1.2 -> 01.20
...
```

I have been trying to work with precision, but it makes the precision fixed.

Is there an equivalent method in Qt? I have been looking for documentation for a long time and can't find anything similiar, and my best result so far padding and precision, but the problem is I can't append both begginning and end of result string when working with padding(e.g. `1.2 -> 01.20`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure `0.535353 -> 00.5353` is correct, do you want a value to be truncated (floored) to set precision before formatting or rounded to precision?

```cpp
double floorWithPrec(double value, int prec) {
    return floor(abs(value) * pow(10.0, prec)) / pow(10.0, prec) * (value < 0 ? -1.0 : 1.0);
}

int countIntDigits(double value, int prec) {
    double t = round(abs(value) * pow(10.0, prec)) / pow(10.0, prec);
    return t >= 1.0 ? log10(t) + 1 : 0;
}

QString toString(const QString& format, double value, bool truncate = false) {
    int fieldWidth0 = format.size();
    int intDigits0 = format.indexOf(".");
    int prec = fieldWidth0 - intDigits0 - 1;
    if (truncate) {
        value = floorWithPrec(value, prec);
    }
    int intDigits = countIntDigits(value, prec);
    int fieldWidth = qMax(intDigits0, intDigits) + 1 + prec + (value < 0 ? 1 : 0);
    QString formated = QString("%1").arg(value, fieldWidth, 'f', prec, QChar('0'));
    int trim = 0;
    while (format.size() - trim - 1 > -1
           && formated.size() - trim - 1 > -1
           && format[format.size() - trim - 1] == "#"
           && formated[formated.size() - trim - 1] == "0")  {
        trim++;
    }
    return formated.mid(0, formated.size() - trim);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QString format = "00.00##";

    Q_ASSERT(toString(format, 1.23) == "01.23");
    Q_ASSERT(toString(format, 10) == "10.00");

    Q_ASSERT(toString(format, 0.535353, true) == "00.5353");
    Q_ASSERT(toString(format, 0.535353, false) == "00.5354");

    Q_ASSERT(toString(format, 831.5) == "831.50");
    Q_ASSERT(toString(format, 1.2) == "01.20");

    Q_ASSERT(toString(format, 99.99999, false) == "100.00");
    Q_ASSERT(toString(format, 99.99999, true) == "99.9999");

    Q_ASSERT(toString(format, -1.23) == "-01.23");
    Q_ASSERT(toString(format, -99.99999, false) == "-100.00");
    Q_ASSERT(toString(format, -99.99999, true) == "-99.9999");

    Q_ASSERT(toString(format, 1e-7, true) == "00.00");
    Q_ASSERT(toString(format, 1e-7, false) == "00.00");

    Q_ASSERT(toString(format, -1e-7, true) == "00.00");
    Q_ASSERT(toString(format, -1e-7, false) == "-00.00");

    Q_ASSERT(toString(format, 0.0, true) == "00.00");
    Q_ASSERT(toString(format, 0.0, false) == "00.00");

    return 0;
}
```